# How the mod() function works internally in languages like Java, Python, etc?

Tags: python, java, algorithm, math, numerical-methods

in Java or Python this function is given by the % operator.
I would like to know the mathematical algorithm that uses this function.

Comment: Read the relevant sections of the language specs, e.g. [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3). Note that % in Java is the remainder operator, not the mod operator, and has different semantics to e.g. python.

Comment: [How does Python implement the modulo operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198308/how-does-python-implement-the-modulo-operation)

Comment: The mod (or %) operator is usually not implemented at the language level, but invokes the native function supported by the processor itself. The processor probably uses the same machinery as for the division, but the details are not disclosed.